# ICombinable .NET Interface

Tags: c#, .net

I'm finding myself in need of "combining" several instances of the same type. This type has several IList properties on it. I want to take each instance and combine the values of those IList properties across the instances, so my code only needs one of those instances.

I'm thinking of creating an ICombinable interface, but I'm wonder if there's something already out there that's suited to this?

```
   public interface ICombinable<T>
    {
        void CombineWith(T instance);
    }
```

Comment: sounds like a code smell to me.....?

Comment: More info, please. How would you use this interface?

Comment: @ Mitch: Code smell? What's that?

Comment: More info: I have a MyConfigurationInfo object that I get from 1. A file, 2. A database. Each MyConfigurationInfo has a List<string> They can each exist independently, but if both exist, I don't want to have to look in both instances for some string. I just want one instance with all the info I need. So, let's say I want just one static property I can use like MyProgram.MyConfigurationInfo, which would have the info combined from the two.

Comment: What do you do if a key exists in both places with different values?

Comment: Perhaps preserve duplication, perhaps overwrite...which is why the implementing class would need to define the implementation for combining with another class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using SelectMany and Select for this. IConfiguration is an interface for the MyConfigurationInfo class. GetMyConfigurationSources returns all the different IConfigurations (from files, DB, etc).

```
    // accumulates an enumerable property on IConfiguration
    public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetConfigurationValues<TValue>(Func<IConfiguration, IEnumerable<TValue>> selector)
    {
        // cast included for clarification only
        return (GetMyConfigurationSources() as IEnumerable<IConfiguration>)
            .Where(c => selector(c) != null)
            .SelectMany(selector);
    }

    // accumulates a non enumerable property on IConfiguration
    public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetConfigurationValues<TValue>(Func<IConfiguration, TValue> selector)
    {
        // cast included for clarification only
        return (GetMyConfigurationSources() as IEnumerable<IConfiguration>)
            .Where(c => selector(c) != null)
            .Select(selector);
    }

    // Example usage:
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] allEnumerableValues = GetConfigurationValues(c => c.SomeEnumerableConfigPropertyOfStrings);
        string[] allNonEnumerableValues = GetConfigurationValues(c => c.SomeNonEnumerableConfigPropertyString);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`? If you add the same thing multiple times, only 1 item exists.

Comment: The question wasn't so much about how to distinct the values, but rather how to aggregate them and access them in a fluent way. Though +1, as incorporate a unique-ing HashSet into the Select/SelectMany solution below is a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need `Concat`

```
var configs = dbConfig.configList.Concat(fileConfig.configList);
```

Comment: But I have several of these configLists on fileConfig and dbConfig that need concatanating...and then I want them all accessible through a single instance of MyConfigurationInfo

Comment: There is definitely not enough information here for a comparison to an existing solution, but it sounds like you are trying to oversimplify your configuration. I'd recommend that you take a step back and analyze your design. Why do you have multiple sources of configuration info? If there is a valid reason, then you should be able to build a provider based on that logic that can expose your configuration coherently.  But from your description I'm having a hard time working backwards to the design.

Comment: I have two different configuration sources of the same structure. One is for installation specific configuration information (this is stored in an xml config file). The second is application wide configuration settings that are pulled from a DB over WCF. Does that help?